# Guarantee that type families will derive certain classes

Tags: haskell, type-families

I have something like the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class Configuration c where
    data Pig c
    data Cow c

    parsePig :: GenParser Char st (Pig c)
    parseCow :: GenParser Char st (Cow c)

data Farm c =
    { pigs :: [Pig c]
    , cows :: [Cow c]
    } deriving Show
```

This fails because of the `deriving Show` line. I don't know how to force all `Configuration` instances to ensure that their `data Pig` and `data Cow` implementations are all instances of `Show`.

I know I could make it have `showPig` and `showCow` methods and the write out the whole complex `show` instance, but in reality things are more complex than this and that would be quite a pain.

Is there an easy, elegant way to guarantee that type family instances are themselves instances of certain classes?

Comment: It doesn't fail because of the `LANGAUGE` line?

Comment: That's not the whole file; I pared it down for purposes of this question. Obviously there's a module declaration, a ParserCombinators.Parsec import, and so forth.

Comment: I think Matt meant the fact that the line states `LANGAUGE` while it should be `LANGUAGE`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `StandaloneDeriving` to specify the constraints manually just for the `Show` instance.

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving, FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances #-}
deriving instance (Show (Pig c), Show (Cow c)) => Show (Farm c)
```

This will still let you have `Configuration` instances with `Cow` and `Pig` that don't implement `Show`, however, as long as you don't try to `show` them.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you wanted to *force* all instances of `Configuration` to have `Pig c` and `Cow c` implement `Show`, an even simpler way to do this is to simply constrain the type families in the class's context, like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts #-}

class (Show (Pig c), Show (Cow c)) => Configuration c where
    data Pig c
    data Cow c

data Farm c = Farm { pigs :: [Pig c],
                     cows :: [Cow c] } deriving (Show)
```

EDIT:

As @hammar pointed out in his comment, the previous code won't compile.  One way to fix this is to use `StandaloneDeriving`, as he suggested.  The other way is this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts, GADTSyntax #-}

class (Show (Pig c), Show (Cow c)) => Configuration c where
    data Pig c
    data Cow c

data Farm c where
    Farm :: Configuration c => { pigs :: [Pig c],
                                 cows :: [Cow c] } -> Farm c deriving (Show)
```

These two approaches get you slightly different results, in that @hammar's approach will *require* a `Configuration` constraint if you call `show`, whereas my approach will *make available* said constraint.

Comment: This doesn't compile (using GHC 7.4.1, at least). However, combining this with the `StandaloneDeriving` approach using `deriving instance Configuration c => Show (Farm c)` avoids the need for `UndecidableInstances`.